# Failed to grant "read" permissions to the Managed Instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I create an azure managed instance, I want to set one account to active directory admin ,But I cannot grant "read" permission to the MI like below screenshot

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you do not have an administrator role. You need to have your tenant administrator grant you the **company administrator** or **global administrator**
role.

Log in to Azure as a **global administrator**>Azure AD>users>select user>Assigned roles

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok， thanks ,where can I check the tenant administrator I contact? subscription or resource group?

Comment: @AlexWang  Don't you know your tenant administrator?